# My computer is a mess with Python and Anaconda3. How do I uninstall everything and start again properly?

Tags: anaconda, operating-system, package, uninstallation

When I was getting into Python I had no idea what I was doing. I have a conda3 env, base root env and another. Packages never work and I really have no idea what I've done to get myself here.

Now, as I try to begin developing properly, I want to know whether there are steps I can take to remove everything Python from my computer and start again properly?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: I use Window's (10) OS.

Comment: Then you should be able to simply go to `Add or remove Program` and uninstall any python and anaconda installation that you might have.